# Getting error when Declaring SQL Temp Table on if Statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would just like to seek some help regarding declaring the same temp table on an if else statement. Upon declaring the same temp table on the "Else" statement, I am getting the "object already exist" error - which I can't seem to understand why. Please help me to understand as why this is happening and maybe how this can be better be implemented? Thanks!

```
----------------------------------------------------------
if OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#temptable') IS NOT NULL --Temp Table Checker
        begin
         Drop table #temptable
        end
----------------------------------------------------------
if(@FieldID IS NOT NULL)
    begin
        select * into #temptable from RealTable where
        FieldName like '%'+@Name+'%' or FieldTag like '%'+@Name+'%'
        and FieldID= @FieldID and IsActive = 1
    end
else
    begin
      select * into #temptable from RealTable where ---> Getting Error here '#temptable already exist'
        FieldName like '%'+@Name+'%' or FieldTag like '%'+@Name+'%'
         and IsActive = 1
    end
```

Comment: Because you declared it twice in the same batch. do `CREATE TABLE` before the `IF` instead of `into #temptable`

Comment: Without parentheses you will likely be surprised about what happens when you combine OR and AND

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table names are unique identifiers. As such the name of a table must be unique in the context of a batch, like Charlieface commented.

If it is always the same structure, then initiate the temporary table like:

```
SELECT * INTO #temptable FROM RealTable WHERE 1=0;
```

This copies the *structure* only. Using this approach also works if the source tables have different structures.

In your IF statement you can use different INSERT statements to copy data from your real tables into an existing temporary table in different ways.

And do not forget to drop the temp table once you are finished with it. While the temp table goes out of scope once a procedure or context finishes the re-use of the same name can yield to problems on a busy server. Just talking from experience.